# How to take backup(.bak) in SQL Server on linux

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, visual-studio-code

I  can not take backup  **.bak**  from my database in Linux ubuntu

See this image I want to backup from conn1 database: CarSaleDatabase

[image]

I run this

```
USE CarSaleDatabase
GO 

BACKUP DATABASE CarSaleDatabase
TO DISK = '/home/mohammadsgh/github/ddblab.bak'
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Cannot open backup device
>   '/home/mohammadsgh/github/ddblab.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). 
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

How can I do this?

Comment: You didn't actually show us the SQL you ran...

Comment: That's a hyperlink, to documentation. That doesn't tell us what SQL *you* ran...

Comment: You back up a database by running SQL... Specifically the `BACKUP DATABASE` statement. What was the SQL you ran the get the error..? We can't help you if you don't he'll us help you

Comment: USE CarSaleDatabase
GO 

BACKUP DATABASE CarSaleDatabase
TO DISK = '\home\mohammadsgh\github\dblab.bak'

Comment: and this is my error:Msg 3038, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The file name "\home\mohammadsgh\github\dblab.bak" is invalid as a backup device name. Reissue the BACKUP statement with a valid file name. 
 
 Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: You should be using the [edit] feature to tell is that. As for the error, Linux doesn't use `\\ ` for directory separators, it uses `/`. Also, I doubt that the `mssql` user/group has access to that directory.

Comment: I edit this post what you mean 'I doubt that the mssql user/group has access to that directory.'

Comment: I can't really expand much more on that. I doubt that the user `mssql` or the group `mssql` has access to the directory you want to back up in. It also probably shouldn't, seeing as it's a user's home directory

Answer (score 0):

> First step

create `.bak` file:

```
touch db.bak
```

> second step:

```
sudo chmod 777 db.bak
```

Comment: Why do you need to give everyone permission to the file? That seems unnecessary.